# iPhone 5 won't turn on after being off for two weeks

Tags: hardware, battery, charging

The iPhone was perfectly working. Then it was left home for two weeks. Battery obviously drained out.

When I came back, I put the iPhone on the charger for *a lot* time. However, the iPhone and the charger were cold, like nothing is really charging. Charger works, have tested it with a different iPhone.

So now my iPhone still can't be turned on!

How can this be possible?

Edit: I tried hard reset combination, tried to connect to laptop, different chargers...

Comment: Connect it to a laptop especially the one that you back it up with - may just be different. Also please edit the title ....

Comment: @SolarMike thanx, tried that already :( title fixed

Comment: Why don't you try another battery?

Comment: Have you tried to leave it charging for a few hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing helped, it was simply unusable.